# How do I render a page for nested routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

To learn rails, I started to write my own (stripped down) version of reddit. Currently, I have my comments routes nested inside my post routes as such:

```
resources :posts do 
 resources :comments
end
```

For my comments controller, under index & create I have the following

```
def index 
        @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
        @comments = @post.comments

        if params[:comment].nil? 
            @comment = Comment.new 
            @comment.post_id = @post.id
        else 
            @comment = Comment.find([:comment])
        end 
    end 

    def create 
        @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
        @comment.user_id = current_user.id
        @comment.post_id = params[:post_id]

        if @comment.save 
            #flash 
            redirect_to post_path(@comment.post)
        else 
            #flash
            render 'index'
        end 
    end
```

Which works well, except the last part: render

I want my comments to display on the same page as the other comments (just like reddit), so I would prefer not use the www.example.com/post/4/comment/new path, and instead do it through the www.example.com/post/4/comments path.

I understand that I can do a redirect, however I want to keep the comment text, so the user can make corrections. Is there a way to properly do this with a render, as opposed to me putting the text in a session variable and doing a redirect? I understand this is an edge case, but am trying to use this as a learning opportunity.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the comment to the index partial - no?

```
<%= render "index", locals: {comment: @comment} %>
```

Or try a partial;

```
<%= render partial: "index", locals: {comment: @comment} %>
```